# How to add supplementary header view for an empty section in collectionView custom layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that displays a custom layout, **not** the trivial flow layout. with supplementary headers for each `section` of items.

Now, I know this doesn't make a lot of UX sense, but for good reasons I need to add a supplementary header for an **empty** section. The thing is, iOS doesn't display the header unless it has items in the section.

I have come across some suggestions to this particular matter, however, they all apply to a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and I am dealing with a custom layout.

Anyone with an efficient solution for this matter?

Comment: return a single cell for the empty section with height as 0.1 that way you have one item in your section and height of that item is so small that no body sees it. Make the item cell transparent and add no UI element to it if needed :)

Comment: So I added an item but you don't need to modify the height or background. I simply set `isHidden = true` for the item. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, in addition to the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols, it will trigger the desired methods to size, and display, the header and footer views, even when there are no items.

```
class YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
   ...
}
```

You to not need to implement any of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods, just have your class implement the protocol.